# Create a blank vector of dates

Tags: r, date

How can I define a blank vector which can handle dates?

For example:

```
# this doesn't work ... produces error message
test_vct <- vector(mode = "Date")

# this works but
test_vct <- vector(mode = "double")
dte_current_upper <- as.Date("2014-12-31")


test_vct <- c(test_vct, as.Date("2014-12-31"))
# this displays as 16435
test_vct

# a vector of dates is possible but how to define a blank vector ?
vct_dates <- c(as.Date("2014-12-31"), as.Date("2013-12-31"))
class(vct_dates)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to do. You want something like `xts::xts(order.by=Sys.Date()+0:10)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see other answers

---

the simplest maybe?

```
vct_dates <- vector()
class(vct_dates)="Date"
```

Comment: @Pascal Now I know : And I deleted first one

Comment: This is a bad solution for two reasons: 1) `vector()` creates a logical vector by default (compare (`str(vct_dates)` with `str(Sys.Date())`), and 2) you generally shouldn't call `class` directly in order to create an object of that class (you should use a constructor or the `as.` method).

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
as.Date(NA)
```

Here's a test:

```
> c(as.Date(NA), 0)
[1] NA           "1970-01-01"
```

Can also construct an all-NA vector:

```
as.Date(rep(NA, 10))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `structure()` with `integer()`.  This creates an empty vector of mode *integer* but class *Date*, which can later be used in calculations.  You can assign to `x` using character vectors.

```
x <- structure(integer(), class = "Date")
x
# character(0)
class(x)
# [1] "Date"
x[1] <- "2015-08-12"
x - Sys.Date()
# Time difference of -175 days
```